# How to try convert a generic enumeration using Enum.TryParse

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to write a generic method which uses Enum.Tryparse. Below is code snippet which I'm using.

```
  Type @enum = typeof(REPORT_FREQUENCY);
  var selectedValue = REPORT_FREQUENCY.DAILY;
  if (Enum.TryParse(selectedValue.ToString(), out @enum.UnderlyingSystemType value))
     { 
       //do something
     }
```

However I'm getting this error message "@enum is a variable ,but used like a type". What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a data type and an instance of the `Type` class.

Comment: What would the `do something` be? If you don't know the actual type then you can't do anything. If you do know it then you may as well do `if (Enum.TryParse<REPORT_FREQUENCY>(selectedValue, out REPORT_FREQUENCY value))` although quite what the point of the whole thing is is not clear.

Comment: An object of type `System.Type` cannot be used as an actual type. Types must be known at **compile-time** since C# is a strongly typed language. A `Type` object contains meta-data about a type at **run-time**. Generic type parameters must be known at compile-time as well, i.e., they are not dynamic.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, In my use case the enumeration type is dynamic .so what I'm looking for is a generic way, . That is instead "Enum.TryParse<REPORT_FREQUENCY>" something like Enum.TryParse<T>. Is that feasible ?

Comment: Since `selectedValue` is an enum already, I don't understand why you convert it to a string just to parse it afterwards. If you have different enums, you can convert their values to an `int` as a common base to deal with different types of enums.

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass the enum type directly to the `Enum.TryParse()` ?

```
var enumType = typeof(REPORT_FREQUENCY);
object parsedValue;
if (Enum.TryParse(enumType, selectedValue.ToString(), out parsedValue))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the generic version `Enum.TryParse<REPORT_FREQUENCY>(selectedValue, out REPORT_FREQUENCY value)`

Comment: @Charlieface because you can cast object to the parsed value to the appropriate enumeration type.

Comment: I don't understand: if you use the generic version then you already have it in the correct type, no need to cast.

Comment: I mean, both of the solutions are correct.